# How can you ignore from cin until it goes to the next line?

Tags: c++

If you have a text file that you're reading character by character with cin:

```
char text;
cin >> text;
cout << char << endl;
```

Suppose you want to ignore any lines that start with ">" until the new line, how can you do that?

Comment: easy, run it and go for a walk...

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the `char` read for `'>'` using::

```
int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );
```

If found, skip till `char` read equals `'\n'` i.e., skip till `strncmp` returns `0` for `( char, '\n', 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to use std::istream::ignore, something like:

```
static const int max_line = 65536;

if (text == ">")
    std::cin.ignore(max_line, '\n');
```

Note that I've specified a maximum distance to skip of 64K bytes. Many people recommend something like `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`, which basically means to skip *any* amount of text until you find the delimiter (new-line, in this case).

IMO, specifying such a huge number is usually a poor idea -- if you go for *too* long without seeing a new-line, it's safe to stop and assume that you've gotten bad data. As soon as you've read enough to be *reasonably* certain there's a problem, it's better to stop and warn the user, rather than spending minutes with the program apparently locked up, reading gigabytes of useless data (and then probably giving the user an error message anyway).

Another possibility (especially if you're fairly sure you'll get good input) is to start by reading a full line (e.g., with std::getline), then if it starts with a `>`, just skip processing the line, and go back to read the next one.